# Métodos de encadenamiento en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vscode, transbank

Hola que tal gente como van?. Soy yo nuevamente con mi mini aplicación del banco.
Tengo las siguientes instrucciones:[image]

El cual sigo con el siguiente código:

```
class User: # declara una clase y dale el nombre User
    def __init__(self, username, email_address):
        self.name = username
        self.email = email_address
        self.account_balance = 0
    def make_deposit(self, amount): # toma un argumento que es el monto del depósito
        self.account_balance += amount
        return self 
    def display_user_balance(self): # muestra el estado actual del monto de la cuenta
        print(self.name,'Saldo: $',self.account_balance)
        return self
    def make_withdrawal(self, amount):  # toma un argumento que es el monto del retiro
        self.account_balance -= amount
        return self
    def transfer_money (self, other_user, amount): # disminuye el saldo del usuario en la cantidad y agrega esa cantidad al saldo de otro other_user 
        self.account_balance -= amount
        other_user.account_balance += amount
        return self
adolfo = User("adolfo hormazabal", "adolfo@python.com")
guido = User("Guido van Rossum", "guido@python.com")
monty = User("Monty Python", "monty@python.com")
adolfo.make_deposit(100).make_deposit(200).make_deposit(50).make_withdrawal(50).display_user_balance().transfer_money(monty,100)
guido.make_deposit(100).make_deposit(100).make_withdrawal(50).make_withdrawal(50).display_user_balance()
monty.make_deposit(500).make_withdrawal(100).make_withdrawal(100).make_withdrawal(100).display_user_balance()
```

que me tira errores por razones que no entiendo, sigo las instrucciones de lo que me piden y no puedo completar mi programa haciendo métodos de encadenamiento en python.
Porfavor ayúdenme a ver como tengo que hacer el código para que me resulte esto que me esta rompiendo la cabeza porfavor, llevo días en esto y me tira errores de indentación el VScode. Ayuda.

Edit:
El error es el siguiente
python usuario.py
"File "D:\Coding Dojo\Python\Tareas\Python\usuario.py", line 14
return self
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"

Comment: Por que declaras varias clases???

Comment: Solo declara una clase y luego vas creando los métodos, te recomiendo que sepas como es la estructura de una clase

Comment: lo tengo hecho ahora en una clase y me sigue tirando errores.

Comment: Si agregaras los errores podría identificarel origen

Comment: File "D:\Coding Dojo\Python\Tareas\Python\usuario.py", line 8
    return self
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: Esto por ahora no parece un problema de python sino de tu editor de código, habre tu archivo con block de notas y verifica la indentación, también tendrías que corregirla en tu editor de código

Comment: el problema es que si muevo un return hacia adelante me dice que esta mal, y si lo muevo hacia atras me anula o me mata el codigo hacia abajo el return.

Comment: te digo que la configuración de tu editor esta mal y que abras el archivo con block de notas

Comment: ok, supongamos que VScode está mal. Como puedo hacer lo que me pides?

Comment: quieres que haga esto? https://imgur.com/a/2QhCw3p

Comment: Tienes que configurar el tipo de indentacion con la que trabajaras, python acepta 2 i 4 espacios y eso lo tienes que co figurar en vscode. Creo que tenías que presionar `ctrl + p` y buscar `indentation`

Comment: edite el post, miralo, ahora tengo el mismo error en la linea 14. Cuando pongo ctrl+p, me tira los archivos con los que he trabajado.

Comment: sinceramente no sé como explicarte los pasos, yo tuve el mismo problema y jugando con la configuración de los tabs de vscode lo arreglé

Comment: no sé que ocurre. Comencé arreglar los errores y me lleva a arreglar el codigo tal como lo tenía antes, usando esto. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: tu problema es un problema de configuración y esto hace que tu problema no se pueda reproducir y posiblemente tu pregunta termine cerrad